# what does stack keyword in ARM assembly do

Tags: assembly, arm

In the following code which i am running in ARM7 big endian and getting the error - 
**the.s(29): error: A1163E: Unknown opcode pointer , expecting opcode or Macro** 
The error is specifically at code: **stack pointer** 
The stack is initially mentioned also in a previous line - `ADR sp, stack` 
and near the last line - `stack DCD 0x0 ; Base of the stack <br>`

```
AREA Replace_THE, CODE, READONLY
                ENTRY
                ADR r0, STRING1             ;Set r0 to point to STRING1
                ADR r1, EoS                 ;Set r1 to point to EoS
                ADR r2, STRING2             ;Set r2 to point to STRING2
                SUB r1, r0                  ; Get the length of STRING1, which will be used
                                            ; as loop counter for the index of STRING1
                ADD r1, #1                  ; Add 1 to r1 to handle the null termination
                ADR sp, stack               ; Set up the stack pointer
CheckFirst      LDRB r3, [r0]               ; Load r3 with the first ASCII character of
                                            ; current STRING1
                BL CheckIfThe               ; Jump to subroutine CheckIfThe, where it
                                            ; checks if r3 is part of the character "the"
                CMP r1, #1                  ; Performs test to see if r1 is 1 or not
                STRBEQ r3, [r2], #1         ; IF TRUE, then store r3 into STRING2, then
                                            ; point to next location to store a character
                BEQ ENDPROG                 ; IF TRUE, then end program
CheckString     LDRB r3, [r0], #1 ; Load r3 with the first ASCII character of
                        ; current STRING1, then point to next character
                STRB r3, [r2], #1 ; Store r3 into STRING2, then point to next
                                ; location to store a character
                CMP r3, #0x20 ; Performs test to see if r3 is equal to 0x20
                            ; which is SPACE in ASCII character
                BLEQ CheckIfThe ; IF TRUE, then jump to subroutine CheckIfThe
                SUBS r1, #1 ; Decrement the loop counter
                BNE CheckString ; Loop again, continue until r1 equals zero
ENDPROG         B ENDPROG ; Infinite loop
CheckIfThe      STMFD sp!, {r0, r1, r3, lr} ; Save the working registers and link register at
stack pointer
                LDRB r3, [r0], #1           ; Load r3 with the first ASCII character of
                            ; current STRING1, then point to next character
                SUBS r1, #1                  ; Decrement the loop counter   
                CMP r3, #0x74               ; Performs test to see if r3 is equal to 0x74
                            ; which is "t" in ASCII character
                LDMFDNE sp!, {r0, r1, r3, pc} ; IF FALSE, restore registers and force a return
                LDRB r3, [r0], #1            ; Load r3 with the first ASCII character of
                            ; current STRING1, then point to next character
                SUBS r1, #1                 ; Decrement the loop counter
                CMP r3, #0x68                   ; Performs test to see if r3 is equal to 0x68
                                ; which is "h" in ASCII character
                LDMFDNE sp!, {r0, r1, r3, pc} ; IF FALSE, restore registers and force a return
                LDRB r3, [r0], #1               ; Load r3 with the first ASCII character of
                            ; current STRING1, then point to next character
                SUBS r1, #1                     ; Decrement the loop counter
                CMP r3, #0x65               ; Performs test to see if r3 is equal to 0x65
                            ; which is "e" in ASCII character
                LDMFDNE sp!, {r0, r1, r3, pc} ; IF FALSE, restore registers and force a return
                LDRB r3, [r0]               ; Load r3 with the first ASCII character of
                            ; current STRING1
                CMP r3, #0x20                ; Performs test to see if r3 is equal to 0x20
                            ; which is SPACE in ASCII character
                CMPNE r3, #0x00                 ; IF FALSE, Performs test to see if r3 is equal to 
                            ; 0x00 which is null in ASCII character
                LDMFDNE sp!, {r0, r1, r3, pc} ; IF FALSE, restore registers and force a return
                MOV pc, lr                  ; ELSE, copy linked register into PC and return it
STRING1         DCB "and the man said they must go" ; String1
EoS             DCB 0x00                ; End of string1
STRING2         space 0xFF          ; String3, where the results are stored in
                SPACE 0x40                  ; Reserved room for stack to grow
stack           DCD 0x0                 ; Base of the stack
                END
```

How to resolve this error? what could be the reason for this?

Comment: That is a comment. It accidentally got wrapped to the next line. Either put it back at the end of the previous line where it belongs, or put a semicolon before it to make it a comment on its own.

Comment: Oh yes it worked. Apart from that what is this line doing - ADR sp, stack    There is a reference to it near the end - stack  DCD 0x0. Is this some special symbol called stack or just a normal label?

Comment: It's a normal label. Since stack grows down, it's placed at the end of a chunk of memory set aside for stack use.